# Error 500 response is not committed

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, httpresponse, requestdispatcher

I am trying to send a request to my jsp page i.e manufacturer details and get the attribute via session, but it throws a 500 error.

```java
    package com.osahub.disaster.controller;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import static com.osahub.disaster.controller.Ofymethodadmin.ofy;

    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;

       import com.osahub.disaster.controller.SendMail;

        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
         public class admin extends HttpServlet {
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("Data Saved!");

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        String name= req.getParameter("name");
        String address = req.getParameter("address");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String website = req.getParameter("website");
        String topex = req.getParameter("topex");
        String topdes = req.getParameter("topdes");
        String topmob = req.getParameter("topmob");
        String year = req.getParameter("year");
        String brand = req.getParameter("brand");
        String factory = req.getParameter("factory");
        String sector = req.getParameter("sector");
        String contactpername = req.getParameter("contactpername");
        String contactperdes = req.getParameter("contactperdes");
        String contactpermob = req.getParameter("contactpermob");

        HttpSession currentSession=req.getSession();
        currentSession.setAttribute("name", name);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("ManufacturerDetails.jsp").forward(req, resp);


        SendMail mail = new SendMail();
        mail.send(email, "send Test mail from gae" , "this is the mail body");



        ManufacturerDetails ad = new ManufacturerDetails(name,address,email,website,topex,topdes,topmob,year,brand,factory,sector,contactpername,contactperdes,contactpermob);
        ofy().save().entity(ad);
        ofy().clear();

        List<ManufacturerDetails> li = ofy().load().type(ManufacturerDetails.class).list();
        Iterator<ManufacturerDetails> iter = li.iterator();

        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            ManufacturerDetails ad1 = iter.next();
            System.out.println(ad1.getName());
            System.out.println(ad1.getAddress());
            System.out.println(ad1.getEmail());
            System.out.println(ad1.getWebsite());
            System.out.println(ad1.getTopex());
            System.out.println(ad1.getTopdes());
            System.out.println(ad1.getTopmob());
            System.out.println(ad1.getYear());
            System.out.println(ad1.getBrand());
            System.out.println(ad1.getFactory());
            System.out.println(ad1.getSector());
            System.out.println(ad1.getContactpername());
            System.out.println(ad1.getContactpermob());
            System.out.println(ad1.getContactperdes());

        }
    resp.sendRedirect("about.jsp");


    }
    }
```

Comment: What's in the error log?

Answer (score 1):

A response with HTTP status code 500 can be caused by any exception.

However, it looks like in your case the exception is thrown because you call `resp.sendRedirect("about.jsp");` after `req.getRequestDispatcher("ManufacturerDetails.jsp").forward(req, resp);`.

You cannot do that, because once the call to `forward()` completes, the response is committed. However, it does not mean that `doPost()` method returns control, it keeps executing. Thus, `resp.sendRedirect("about.jsp");` causes `java.lang.IllegalStateException` exception to be thrown, since the response is already closed.

You have to review your method, and introduce a conditional statement:

```
if (condition) {
    // do something
    req.getRequestDispatcher("ManufacturerDetails.jsp").forward(req, resp);
} else {
    // do something
    resp.sendRedirect("about.jsp");
}
```

Another option is to introduce an explicit `return` after `req.getRequestDispatcher("ManufacturerDetails.jsp").forward(req, resp);`.

Comment: @Shubham Malik Or maybe you'll need to call `include` instead of `forward`.

Comment: @LittleSanti Very good point. However, from this code listing it is not clear what should be the correct flow. Either he wants to forward/redirect depending on some condition or he wants to "include" the processing done by `ManufacturerDetails.jsp`.

Answer (score 0):

500 exception occurs due to the server problem .  It is cause because you can write both code - getRequestDispatcher and sendRedirect for execute . And this is not possible . You can not do this because after once send the request paramater it terminate . So you can write both code in if-else condition .